# WordPress have_posts returns false but should return true

Tags: php, wordpress

In the WordPress theme I have, when a contact form is completed a message is written on the page but not at the location I want it to be. But when changing the location of the message in the PHP code, the paragraph that goes with the contact form (written in an article) doesn't show up anymore. In fact, I think that the `have_posts` method returns false and so the `php_content` method isn't called.

Here is the original code :

```
<div id="main" class="site-main container_16">
        <div class="inner">
            <div id="primary" class="grid_11 suffix_1">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
                    <div class="alert green">
                        <?php _e( 'Thanks, your email was sent successfully.', 'wplook' ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php if(isset($hasError) ) { ?>
                        <p class="error"><?php _e( 'Sorry, an error occured.', 'wplook' ); ?><p>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contact-form" method="post"> ...
```

And here is how I want it to be :

```
<div id="main" class="site-main container_16">
        <div class="inner">
            <div id="primary" class="grid_11 suffix_1">

                <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
                    <div class="alert green">
                        <?php _e( 'Thanks, your email was sent successfully.', 'wplook' ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php if(isset($hasError) ) { ?>
                        <p class="error"><?php _e( 'Sorry, an error occured.', 'wplook' ); ?><p>
                    <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contact-form" method="post">...
```

As you can see, I only changed the location of the confirmation message. But in the second way, the condition with the `have_posts` does not seem to be true since the text I wrote in the article does not show up.

Can someone help me with this issue please ?

Thanks a lot !

Edit:

`var_dump($wp_query)` displays this:

object(WP_Query)#195 (49) { ["query"]=> array(2) { ["page"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(22) "accueil/nous-rejoindre" } ["query_vars"]=> array(62) { ["page"]=> int(0) ["pagename"]=> string(14) "nous-rejoindre" ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(14) "nous-rejoindre" ["static"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["comments_popup"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=> bool(false) ["cache_results"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=> bool(true) ["post_type"]=> string(0) "" ["posts_per_page"]=> int(10) ["nopaging"]=> bool(false) ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2) "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false) ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" } ["tax_query"]=> NULL ["meta_query"]=> object(WP_Meta_Query)#75 (2) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> NULL } ["date_query"]=> bool(false) ["queried_object"]=> object(WP_Post)#74 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(28) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-07-24 12:51:54" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-07-24 11:51:54" ["post_content"]=> string(1257) "Rejoindre WiN France c’est...[content of my page]" ["post_title"]=> string(14) "Nous rejoindre" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(14) "nous-rejoindre" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-07-26 18:06:47" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-07-26 17:06:47" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(8) ["guid"]=> string(41) "http://www.win-france.org/win/?page_id=28" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } ["queried_object_id"]=> int(28) ["request"]=> string(172) "SELECT winfrance_posts.* FROM winfrance_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (winfrance_posts.ID = '28') AND winfrance_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY winfrance_posts.post_date DESC " ["posts"]=> &array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_Post)#73 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(28) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-07-24 12:51:54" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-07-24 11:51:54" ["post_content"]=> string(1257) "Rejoindre WiN France c’est...[content of my page]" ["post_title"]=> string(14) "Nous rejoindre" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(14) "nous-rejoindre" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-07-26 18:06:47" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-07-26 17:06:47" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(8) ["guid"]=> string(41) "[link of my page]" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } } ["post_count"]=> int(1) ["current_post"]=> int(-1) ["in_the_loop"]=> bool(false) ["post"]=> object(WP_Post)#73 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(28) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-07-24 12:51:54" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-07-24 11:51:54" ["post_content"]=> string(1257) "Rejoindre WiN France c’est...[content of my page]" ["post_title"]=> string(14) "Nous rejoindre" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(14) "nous-rejoindre" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-07-26 18:06:47" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-07-26 17:06:47" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(8) ["guid"]=> string(41) "http://www.win-france.org/win/?page_id=28" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } ["comment_count"]=> int(0) ["current_comment"]=> int(-1) ["found_posts"]=> int(1) ["max_num_pages"]=> int(0) ["max_num_comment_pages"]=> int(0) ["is_single"]=> bool(false) ["is_preview"]=> bool(false) ["is_page"]=> bool(true) ["is_archive"]=> bool(false) ["is_date"]=> bool(false) ["is_year"]=> bool(false) ["is_month"]=> bool(false) ["is_day"]=> bool(false) ["is_time"]=> bool(false) ["is_author"]=> bool(false) ["is_category"]=> bool(false) ["is_tag"]=> bool(false) ["is_tax"]=> bool(false) ["is_search"]=> bool(false) ["is_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_comment_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_trackback"]=> bool(false) ["is_home"]=> bool(false) ["is_404"]=> bool(false) ["is_comments_popup"]=> bool(false) ["is_paged"]=> bool(false) ["is_admin"]=> bool(false) ["is_attachment"]=> bool(false) ["is_singular"]=> bool(true) ["is_robots"]=> bool(false) ["is_posts_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_post_type_archive"]=> bool(false) ["query_vars_hash"]=> string(32) "763460f55e15fb6827b2ee25a60c558c" ["query_vars_changed"]=> bool(false) ["thumbnails_cached"]=> bool(false) ["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=> NULL }

Comment: This could be unrelated, but I'm noticing something odd about your form tag: `the_permalink` should be called inside of the loop, but yours is happening outside. On the page that renders the form, what is the value of the form's action attribute?

Comment: The value of the form's action attribute is the URL of the page containing the form. Could this be a problem ?

Comment: Does anyone have an other idea?

Comment: Try adding this before the ifs, `var_dump($wp_query);` and add the result to the question (or a link to some code hosting site)

Comment: Done. The content of the text not showing up is in ["post_content"]...

Comment: An answer was posted here yesterday, but I'm not sure why it was taken down. Somebody had mentioned that it doesn't look as if your else statement is being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hiii, i tried your both codes and it is giving post content

I tried following code,

```
<div id="main" class="site-main container_16">
        <div class="inner">
            <div id="primary" class="grid_11 suffix_1">

                <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
                    <div class="alert green">
                        <?php _e( 'Thanks, your email was sent successfully.', 'wplook' ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php if(isset($hasError) ) { ?>
                        <p class="error"><?php _e( 'Sorry, an error occured.', 'wplook' ); ?><p>
                    <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The else condition was indeed not closed... Stupid thing!